# Visual basic .net 2008 Deployment

Tags: vb.net, deployment

Is it possible to make a setup and deployment project in VB.net 2008, every site i have looked at on google says to just select it from the project list. It isnt in the project list for me to select.
Are these types of projects not available in the express version?
How can I make an installer, other than using one of the setup and deployment projects? (I know there is a publish button, but that doesn't make a proper installer and installs to the appdata folder which is not what i want it to do)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this a web project you are trying to deploy on a sever?  Or a windows application?

Comment: And this is a good question, so +1 to you, Dox5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use another program, such as innosetup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), to create a setup.exe.  Microsoft has to give you some reason to purchase their software.

Comment: You beat me too it by a few seconds :(

Answer (score 3):

Express editions do not have these project types.  They support ClickOnce only,  per this chart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(VS.80).aspx

This carries over to the 2008 versions as well.

***Edit - Added***

See here for using ClickOnce from an Express edition:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/10/02/looking-for-setup-and-deployment-project-templates.aspx

Comment: Is there a way i can achieve the same thing using the express edition?

Comment: Not using the Express edition.  You would either need to upgrade to Professional edition or get a third party tool to make the setup.  I doubt you'll find anything free.

Comment: Or you could just deploy your project using ClickOnce, which IS supported.  And with ClickOnce, you can deoply to a network share or a CD.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

It pretty much will do what you need to create an installer package.  Oh yeah, and it's free.

Comment: You beat me to the mention of free!

Comment: +1 to each of you because you both knew of a free tool that actually looks worthwhile.

Comment: I worked with it at my prior job and it took care of most things you needed with no customization.  The only problem I had, was that when I did need to do a customization, it was in Pascal.  Still a great tool overall.